# Check to see if a row or an ID already exist before doing a mass insert on a table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to an insert from one database table to another like this:

```
INSERT INTO factoryDB_Development.dbo.engineList
    SELECT * 
    FROM factoryDB_Staging.dbo.engineList 
    WHERE engineID NOT IN (SELECT engineID 
                           FROM factoryDB_Development.dbo.engineList)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.engineList'

I am assume it's because that ID already exists in `factoryDB_Development.dbo.engineList`.

When I checked online at the Microsoft site, I just saw this:

```
To work around this issue, enable trace flag 8690 to disable the Spool operation
```

Is there a way to check to see if a row or ID already exists before doing the insert?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are validating that engineID doesn't exist in your destination table, my guess is that you are getting duplicates from your original table, hence the error.

Comment: @iceblade thanks!  I think I understand what you mean....is there way to only insert one of the duplicates from the original table? Like if the original 'engineList' table had 3 exact rows of one engineID, could I just insert the 1st one?

Comment: Sure, you can select just the distinct engineID from your source table, and then do a Cross Apply with a top 1 from that same table to get the other columns. That way you'll eliminate the duplicates. You can include an example of your data so we can help you with the query.

Comment: If you are certain that all your duplicate rows are identical, you can just do a select distinct, that will select and insert only 1 row per engineID

Comment: @iceblade would I do: `SELECT DISTINCT *  factoryDB_Staging.dbo.engineList `? thanks

Comment: Yes, if the rows are identical, you can do: Select distinct *  From factoryDB_Staging.dbo.engineList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to avoid inserting record in target table if that record with the same ID already exists.

If the ID column in question is a primary key, you can simply set IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON by recreating the index.

Below is the sample example.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Source](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Target](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--input sample values in source
INSERT INTO [Source] VALUES (1, 'A') , (1, 'A') , (2, 'B')

--insert data from source to target
INSERT INTO Target 
SELECT  * FROM Source

DROP TABLE SOURCE
DROP TABLE TARGET
```